# Rails - renaming a column and then migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Preface: I'm pretty new to Ruby/Rails

So I have a column in my 'Invitations' table called "name" and I wanted to rename it to "team_name." I changed that in my migrate file, then did a rollback, then re-ran migrate.

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.string :token
      t.string :team_name
      t.integer :number_of_uses
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is what my schema looks like now:

```
create_table "invitations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "token"
    t.string   "team_name"
    t.integer  "number_of_uses"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end
```

Then I went and changed all the instances of 'name' to 'team_name' but now I'm getting all sorts of errors. For example,

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates :team_name, presence: true
```

With the spec,

```
describe '#team_name' do
    it { should validate_presence_of :team_name }
  end
```

And rspec failure,

```
5) Invitation#team_name should require team_name to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :team_name }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `team_name=' for #<Invitation:0x007fd39a26def8>
     # ./spec/models/invitation_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Almost all the errors I'm getting are exactly like this one. I made sure to include the change in my Factory as well...I'm not sure what is really going on here. Did I make a mistake when I changed the column name and did another migrate? Again, I'm still learning Rails. Appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The testing environment use its own database schema. Make sure you update your test database as well :

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the migration file name, but you have to perform a few steps:

1. rake db:rollback to the point that queries table is rolled back.
2. Now change the name of migration file, also the contents.
3. Change the name of any Model that may use the table.
4. rake db:migrate